# Bash, Systemd Service, command substitution - Not playing well together

Tags: bash, service, quotes, systemd, command-substitution

I have the following in my `redis@.service` file:

```
...
ExecStop=/bin/bash -c \"/usr/local/bin/redis-cli -p $(echo %i | awk -F \'.\' \'{ print $2 }\') shutdown\"
...
```

Then when I run:

```
sudo systemctl stop redis@redis.6379.test-site.com.service
```

Followed by:

```
sudo systemctl status redis@redis.6379.test-site.com.service
```

I get:

```
...
Process: 10042 ExecStop=/bin/bash -c "/usr/local/bin/redis-cli -p $(echo redis.6379.test-site.com | awk -F '.' '{ print $2 }') shutdown" (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
...
Sep 10 17:36:53 hostname bash[10042]: -p: -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"'
Sep 10 17:36:53 hostname bash[10042]: -p: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

Then if I run:

```
sudo systemctl start redis@redis.6379.test-site.com.service
```

Followed by (taken from the `systemctl status` output):

```
/bin/bash -c "/usr/local/bin/redis-cli -p $(echo redis.6379.test-site.com | awk -F '.' '{ print $2 }') shutdown"
```

Then the command works as expected...

Can anyone shed some light as to what's happening here?

If Systemd is just running the command shown for `ExecStop`, and that command works just fine when run manually, shouldn't it also work when systemd runs it?

I have a feeling it's something to do with the quoting, but I'm too much of a newb at bash to wrap my head around it.

Comment: why don't you put that command in an executable file and put `ExecStop=/path/to/file` in your redis@.service ?

Comment: %i is only available in the .service file.

Comment: pass it as an argument then

Comment: To be honest, I've already worked out a solution, using `EnvironmentFile`'s. That still doesn't solve the issue though. Workarounds are great, but the question still stands. It should work, and there's something wrong with the syntax, which I'd like to get to the bottom of.

Comment: The double quotes in the `ExecStop` directive in the service file should definitely *not* be escaped. I’m not sure if the single quotes should be, but try replacing the `\"`s with `"`s and see where that gets you :)

Comment: What is the output of `echo $PAGER`? Set the pager environment variable to empty and see if the command works `PAGER="" systemctl status redis@redis.6379.test-site.com.service`